# junit without any mocking framework

Tags: java, unit-testing

Let's say i have a method of a class:

```
public String method1(someparameters) {
       //Calls methods of a different objects
       result2 = object2.method2(someparams )
       result3 = object3.method3(someparams)
       // Does bunch of work in method1
       ...................
       ...................
       return result
 }
```

*object2.method2* and *object3.method3* are such that they need not be mocked.
In other words, they can do their work and return result if passed proper params. My question: while writing unit tests for method1, do i mandatorily need to mock calls of object2 and object3? In other words, is mocking mandatory to do in units tests?

Comment: No it isn't mandatory. Some unit test examples without mocking https://github.com/dperezcabrera/jpoker/blob/master/src/test/java/org/poker/api/core/CardTest.java

Answer (score 2):

No, using mocking framework is not mandatory but could be more convenient. Anyway, the best approach is to have object2 and object3 as interfaces and set their implementation via constructor of your class. This way you might to put simple stub implementations for testing purpose. Having too many methods in the interface is the case to think if it breaks single responsibility principle.